# How can I deserialize JSON to an object with a HashMap attribute?

Tags: java, json

Right now I am using Gson to deserialize JSON to Object.

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "hash":"c8b2ce0aacede58da5d2b82225efb3b7",
      "instanceid":"aa49882f-4534-4add-998c-09af078595d1",
      "text":"{\"C_FirstName\":\"\",\"ContactID\":\"2776967\",\"C_LastName\":\"\"}",
      "queueDate":"2016-06-28T01:03:36"
   }
]
```

And my entity object looks like this:

```
public class AppCldFrmContact {
    public String hash;
    public String instanceid;
    public HashMap<String,String> text; 
    public String queueDate;
}
```

If `text` was a `String` data type, everything would be fine. But then I wouldn't be able to access different fields as I want to.

Is there a way to convert given JSON to Object I want?

The error I am getting is: `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 174`, which is understandable if it cannot parse it.

The code doing the parsing:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<AppCldFrmContact>>() {
        }.getType();
List<AppCldFrmContact> contacts = gson.fromJson(response.body, listType);
```

Comment: The shown `text` field is a String containing an JSON object, not a JSON object!

Comment: What would it look like if it was a JSON object? Then is there a way to parse that given JSON to the object I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because text field is a JSON map serialized to the string. If it is an actual your data and not a just an example, you can annotate a field with [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) and write your own custom `JsonDeserializer<HashMap<String,String>>` which will make deserialization 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

For you expected result, JSON data should be like below format,

```
[
   {
      "hash":"c8b2ce0aacede58da5d2b82225efb3b7",
      "instanceid":"aa49882f-4534-4add-998c-09af078595d1",
      "text":{"C_FirstName":"","ContactID":"2776967","C_LastName":""},
      "queueDate":"2016-06-28T01:03:36"
   }
]
```